# StrapiV4 : how can I return a Blob from a controller?

Tags: blob, strapi

I have a method within a Strapi controller that retrieves a Blob object:

```
export(ctx){
  const body = ctx.request.body;
  const { playlist,format } = body;

  const blob = strapi
    .plugin('spiff')
    .service('playlists')
    .export(playlist,format);

  ctx.body = blob

}
```

But when I check my endpoint in Postman, I get an empty object `{}`.
I checked and rechecked again, my blob IS correctly loaded.

If I convert the blob to a regular object, I get the data :

```
async export(ctx){
  const body = ctx.request.body;
  const { playlist,format } = body;

  const blob = strapi
    .plugin('spiff')
    .service('playlists')
    .export(playlist,format);

  //convert blob to an object
  const blobObj = {
    type:blob.type,
    text:await blob.text()
  }

  ctx.body = blobObj

}
```

Which makes me think that there is a middleware, or something about security maybe, that resets my response.

How can I have my Blob returned correctly ?